# How can I set linking to slides

Tags: wordpress, slider

How can I set links to slides (by clicking on certain slide to be redirected to another page), in the slider of the wordpress theme **View Eightmedi Lite** ?

Comment: This question is outside the scope of Stack Overflow. Please see https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 0):

Use anchor tag and put it inside [wordpress loop](https://codex.wordpress.org/The_Loop):

```
<a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>">View</a>
```